# Wordpress on WAMP localhost won´t let install templates

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, localhost, runtime-error

I have an issue here with Wordpress themes, I get an error no matter what theme I try to install.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function of_get_option() in C:\wamp\www\wp-content\themes\Monaco\slide.php on line 4
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0007  669088  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0011  673872  require( 'C:\wamp\www\wp-blog-header.php' ) ..\index.php:17
3   0.4489  27395224    require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\wp-includes\template-loader.php' )   ..\wp-blog-header.php:16
4   0.4516  27410496    include( 'C:\wamp\www\wp-content\themes\Monaco\index.php' ) ..\template-loader.php:47
5   0.4787  27444544    get_template_part( )    ..\index.php:17
6   0.4787  27445320    locate_template( )  ..\general-template.php:128
7   0.4791  27445432    load_template( )    ..\template.php:381
8   0.4796  27472472    require( 'C:\wamp\www\wp-content\themes\Monaco\slide.php' ) ..\template.php:407
```

I´m getting pretty depressed about the issue and can´t figure out what might be causing this. I reinstalled Wordpress for twice and tried with different templates, still no good. It seems to word fine with themes included by Wordpress but won´t work out with any other.

Can anyone please help me out. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is definitely related to the themes you're trying to install. They refer to a function (`of_get_option()`) that doesn't exist in the standard WordPress installation.

Fortunately there's a forum post with a similar issue here: [WP Support Forums](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/of_get_option-equal-to-get_option).

The function belongs to a plugin. Hope this helps.

Comment: Worth pointing out that the first thing to do when debugging WP is disable all plugins and then re-enable one by one until either you've identified the cause or all the plugins are enabled.

Comment: Well, thanks, that lead me to what you just told, all the themes I downloaded use the same plugin Options Framework. I actually don´t need this so I just try to remove all the settings connected to this plugin.

Comment: Thaks martinCzerwi, the problem was that the plugin was not installed :)